# Ionic Barcode Scanning Process Crash in Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode

I have used the cordova plugin `https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/`

Where I need to scan multiple barcodes but after a scan or more the Android App crashes. It works fine on IOS devices.

Here is crash log:

> 11-20 18:45:39.923 30115-30115/com.xyz.optilockdev
>   E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 =
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path:
>   DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>   11-20 18:45:53.258 30115-30115/com.xyx.optilockdev
>   E/ViewRootImpl@940705f[MainActivity]: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not
>   valid. 11-20 18:46:06.928 30115-30188/com.xyz.optilockdev
>   E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode$1@7c72892
>       at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1352)
>       at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1553)
>       at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:723)
>       at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode.stopService(BackgroundMode.java:256)
>       at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode.disableMode(BackgroundMode.java:166)
>       at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode.execute(BackgroundMode.java:107)
>       at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
>       at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
>       at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
>       at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
>       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 11-20 18:46:45.624 30115-30115/com.xyz.optilockdev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main   Process: com.xyx.optilockdev, PID: 30115
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.xyz.optilockdev/com.xyz.optilockdev.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode$1@7c72892
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3844)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3885)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode$1@7c72892
>       at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1352)
>       at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1553)
>       at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:723)
>       at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode.stopService(BackgroundMode.java:256)
>       at de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode.onResume(BackgroundMode.java:139)
>       at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.onResume(PluginManager.java:264)
>       at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.handleResume(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:450)
>       at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onResume(CordovaActivity.java:275)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1277)
>       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7115)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3821)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3885)
>
> ```
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:67
> ```

Comment: Can you post your code please? and also your Manifest

Comment: @SunnyShah Looks to be an issue with cordova-plugin-background-mode not barcode scanning plugin as per the trace. plz check out -  https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/204

Comment: @SunnyShah Can you confirm whether you are using background plugin?

Comment: @Gandhi yes i am using background plugin and it works fine when i remove code of enable background mode. Thanks

Comment: @SunnyShah Have posted the answer Sunny. Please accept the answer and close in on the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as issue with background plugin not bar-code scanning plugin as per the error trace mentioned by OP.

The crash issue is still open in background plugin as per the [issue link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/204) with no resolution on this yet.

Removing the background plugin for now should resolve the crash issue while bar-code scanning.